# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.lite.python.convert_saved_model' has no attribute 'convert'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert my premade DNN Model to tflite file, using the function:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.lite.python import convert_saved_model
convert_saved_model.convert(saved_model_dir=saved_model, output_tflite="/TF_Lite_Model")
```

I have the last verison of tensorflow installed 1.10
I am using UBUNTU 16.04

the error is the following:

**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.lite.python.convert_saved_model' has no attribute 'convert'**

Answer (score 4):

The API for converting SavedModels to TensorFlow Lite FlatBuffers is `TocoConverter.from_saved_model` as documented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/python_api.md#exporting-a-savedmodel-). The documentation has been copied below.

To provide a general explanation. `from_saved_model` is a classmethod that returns a [`TocoConverter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lite/TocoConverter) object. `TocoConverter` has a function `convert`. `convert_saved_model` is a function and therefore does not have its own `convert` function.

**Copied from documentation:**

The following example shows how to convert a SavedModel into a TensorFlow Lite FlatBuffer.

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

For more complex SavedModels, the optional parameters that can be passed into `TocoConverter.from_saved_model()` are input_arrays, input_shapes, output_arrays, tag_set and signature_key. Details of each parameter are available by running `help(tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter)`.

Comment: The link you provided is not available

Comment: A more updated API is available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_saved_model).

Answer (score 0):

I had to compile the tflite contrib module as it was missing on my repo.